# ÖBB ticket : Validity and reservation

Tags: trains, tickets, austria

I will be travelling from Vienna to Bratislava via train, however i am not clear on 2 points:

- I have booked a specific journey on a particular date however when I look at my date it says "valid: Day 1 until: Day 2". Does it mean that if I miss my train then same ticket can be used over period of 2 days on other train on same route?
- On top of ticket, I can see below screenshot text written, does it mean I require reservation? I don't see any option to reserve a seat.

[image]

Can someone please clarify on these points.

Edit:

I tried to search on other websites and I can see that on trainline it says, no reservation required which seems conflicting to what is mentioned on ticket.
Checking OBB website, they have only given a phone number and no email to clarify this which will be more trickier.

[image]

Comment: Where did you buy that ticket (OBB? ZSSK?)

Comment: I brought ticket on OBB

Comment: The note says that you need a reservation for the Bratislava-Košice route, so irrelevant for your route, Vienna-Bratislava. Why it is there, one may only guess. My guess is that the line on which you will be travelling continues to Košice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bratislava is only a short ride away from Vienna. The trains running between the cities are local trains, that run frequently, and do not require reservations. So you can take any train you want on the days the ticket is valid, on the route you bought it for, not just the train you selected during booking.

That train tickets are flexible is in fact the norm. Also on such short routes there is in fact no advantage in buying tickets in advance. You could have just as easily bought it at the station in Vienna.

Now of all the trains that you can take between Wien and Bratislava one is a daily IC service to Kosice. This train has compulsory reservation between Bratislava and Kosice, but not between Wien and Bratislava, so that is not of concern to you.

Comment: Given that ticket doesn't have time of travel mentioned, I believe validation is required. Is that correct? If yes where can i validate it

Comment: Validation is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Completed my journey, a ticket inspector scanned and checked the ticket.

Answer (score 4):

The text

> IC Bratislava-Kosice/Kosice-Bratislava nur mit Reservierung

means that you can only take an IC (fast) train with a seat reservation. However, your itinerary shows the use of a REX train, on which no seat reservations are necessary or even possible. On this route, it is truly the smart choice to take the REX train, as even though it is a "slower" class of service, it takes a more direct route and so actually will get you to Bratislava faster, for less money.

See [the man in Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/vienna-to-bratislava-by-train.htm) for lots more information on this train, and a confirmation that your ticket is indeed valid on any train on the stamped date or the following day.

Comment: Not quite - you don't need a reservation in the IC between Vienna and Bratislava.